# Colors for menu bar and the scroll bar on emacs 24

Tags: emacs

I'd like to change the colours of the [menu bar](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MenuBar) and the [scroll bar](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ScrollBar) of emacs 24.

The instructions of EmacsWiki (the above links) do not work. This might be because I am using emacs 24.

According to the page [ColorTheme](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme) on EmacsWiki, emacs 24 has a new colour system, so I tried some colour themes and to modify them. (Menu bar→Options→Customize Emacs→Custom Themes) But I could not find the faces which I should customise.

**Could you tell me how to change the colours of the menu bar and the scroll bar of emacs 24?**

Environment: openSUSE 12.3, KDE 4.10.5, Emacs 24.2.1 (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.6.4)

Comment: I'd been wondering about this myself actually. I've gotten as far as finding [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/GTK-resources.html#GTK-resources). I'm pretty sure Emacs uses GTK 3 now, and it seems to want people to edit some CSS file to set specific properties.

Comment: I've prepared gtk.css file, but emacs does not seem to read the file. (I've tried several file locations which are given in the page.) Where do you put gtk.css?

Comment: On Linux easiest way to find the location where emacs looks for the `gtk.css` file is to just use `strace` . See http://superuser.com/questions/1115820/changing-menu-bar-color-of-emacs-gtk3/1126293#1126293 (answer detailing this procedure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the steps which Foof showed, I found the correct path for `gtk.css`.

1) start emacs by the following command, and quit it.

```
$ strace -o strace.log emacs &
```

2) following command will show the path

```
$ grep gtk.css strace.log | grep config
stat("/home/username/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css", 0x7fffc9981d50) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

So I put `gtk.css` at `~/.config/gtk-3.0/`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Emacs 24 does not have a new color system. What it has that is new is a Customize interface for *custom* themes, which are different from but similar to the *color* themes of library `color-theme.el`.
2. I think you mean the *mode line* and not the menu bar. (To change menu-bar appearance I think the only recourse might be Xresources.)
3. The faces to customize are these:

   - `scroll-bar`
   - `mode-line`
   - `mode-line-inactive`
   - `mode-line-emphasis`
   - `mode-line-buffer-id`
   - `mode-line-highlight`

You can customize any of these using `M-x customize-face`.  Or you can define a color theme or a custome theme that uses them.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, adding `gtk.css` to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/` also worked for me. But it was not obvious (to me) what lines to put in that file. After browsing another gtk.css file for a theme on my system (Pocillo), I used this:

```
scrollbar slider {
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
}
scrollbar slider:hover {
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.6);
}
scrollbar slider:active {
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.7);
}
scrollbar slider:disabled {
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.3);
}
```

This is on Ubuntu Budgie 21.10.